# calling a method from the main to output a phrase in java

Tags: java

So I have a method with code and  I want to call this method from the main and have it output "its a mad mad mad mad world" here is the method that I have, I'm not sure why to put in the main to have it output what I want. any ideas?

```
 public static void decisionStatementPractice(int a, int b, double c, char d, boolean e) 
      {
      a += 4;
      d = (char) (d+1);
      if (a + 2 < c || e) 
      {
      System.out.print("It's ");
      }
      if (a <= b && d == 'q') 
      {
       System.out.print("a ");
      }
      else 
      {
      if (d == 'q' && c > 4) 
      {
      System.out.print("a ");
      } 
      else 
      {
      System.out.print("not such a ");
      }
      }
      for (int i=b; i<=7; i+=2) 
      {
      System.out.print("mad ");
      }
      if (!e) 
      {
      System.out.println("world");
      }
       }
```

Comment: Try formatting the code properly first.

Comment: @MikeCAT sorry, i made it more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        decisionStatementPractice(-5,1,2.0, 'p', false);
    }
```

Explanation:

1. Only way you can print "world" is if e = false

   `if (!e)
   {
       System.out.println("world");
   }`
2. To print "a", d has to be equal to 'p' so that d+1 = 'q'

   `if (a <= b && d == 'q') {
       System.out.print("a ");
   }`

   `if (d == 'q' && c > 4) {
       System.out.print("a ");
   }`
3. To print b has to be equal to 1

   `for (int i = b; i <= 7; i += 2) {
       System.out.print("mad ");
   }`
4. At last you have to ensure 2 conditions, (a + 4 + 2 < c) and (a+4 <= b)

   `a += 4;
   if (a + 2 < c || e) {
      System.out.print("It's ");
   }
   if (a <= b && d == 'q') {
       System.out.print("a ");
   }`

So i took a = -5 and c = 2.0

Answer (score 4):

It's basically just gonna have to be how you call it. You'll have to look through the if statements, and find values that make sense. For instance:

```
a += 4;
 if (a + 2 < c || e) {
      System.out.print("It's ");
   }
```

In order for the print statement to execute you're going to have to find a value that is less than c OR e = true. So in this case all you really have to do is pass in a value (in your method main) of e = true; OR a value for int a that is 6 less than double c.

If your asking how to call this method here is a little example:

Let's say your method is in the "OutputWords" class, your call will look something like this:

```
OutputWords words = new OutputWords();
words.decisionStatementPractice(0, 6, 1.5, 'e', true);
```

To answer the last part of your question: You don't NEED to put it into main in order for it to print what you want, you could simply just put that code into your method main and everything would run smoothly. But it is great practice for future assignments you will be doing. It's part of a concept in Object-Oriented Programming, and is a VERY important concept in Java.

Comment: That's the way it is, but the answer is not accurate, try this:decisionStatementPractice(-4, 0, 3, 'p', false);

Comment: thanks @LeoZhao i was trying to print the method in the main, not sure what i was thinking, but I also didnt put values in the parentheses, and as you put the answer saw a similar problem in my book haha, thanks a ton!

Comment: @LeoZhao I wasn't intending on giving the correct parameters, I was going to let him try and figure it out! It looked like a school assignment so I figured he should try and learn how to do it. ;)